# He could be playing with his friends

Tags: modal-verbs, progressive-aspect

John's mother: where is John?

1. John's father: He is not in his room. *He **could be playing** with his friends*.

John's mother: where is John?

2. John's father: He is in his room. He is always reading magazines. *He **could be playing** with his friends*.

Are they both correct? What is the difference between them (the italicized parts)?

Comment: Both are the same, please reread your post.

Comment: #2 says he IS in his room

Comment: But **you said** the italicized parts.

Comment: I think they're really two different uses of "could". I wanted someone to bring out that difference for me.

Comment: No, they are exactly the same. It is the other sentences that are different.

Comment: Then why would a dictionary (links below) provide a number of different nuances of the word "could" (or any other word, for that matter), if "could" means the same thing in all contexts? It looks the same, sounds the same, but still carries a slightly different nuance in a different context. (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/could)...(https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/could) etc

Comment: @Lambie, no, those sentences don't mean the same thing.  They mean something very different.

Comment: In #1, *could be* is pronounced as two separate drawn-out words to signal cognition. In #2, it's pronounced all most as if it's a contraction. Uttered to a native speaker, by a native speaker, there will be zero ambiguity between these two same, yet entirely different sentences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are both correct, and on one level, they both mean the same thing: it is possible that he could be playing with his friends.

On another level, they mean something different; #1 means "It is a realistic possibility that he might be playing with his friends right now (because I do not know what he is doing)", and #2 means "He could be playing with his friends if he wanted to (although I know he is not)".  But that is really more a question of logic and interpretation.

Comment: @Lambie: A sentence can be correct in one context, but not in another - the question asks about one sentence in two similar, but different, contexts.

Comment: @Lambie: I don't know what language the OP speaks, so I can't comment on that. The usage of _could_ is clearly different, because the first _could_ can be validly replaced by _may_, without significantly changing the meaning, whereas the second one cannot.

Comment: see my comment above...

Answer (score 6):

1. suggests that John may actually be playing with his friends (as he is not to be found in his room).
2. suggests that John ought to be playing with his friends (rather than reading in his room).

The second and last sentences of 2. would frequently be joined by **when** to reinforce this point.

Yes, both are correct.

Comment: If, instead of "when", the join in example 2 used "but", we'd have a different meaning, almost intermediate between the other two: he may have friends playing in his room with him (or online these days).

Answer (score 0):

- John's father: He is not in his room. He could be playing with his friends.
- John's father: He is in his room. He is always reading magazines. He could be playing with his friends.

**In both cases, the kid could be playing with this friends.** What is different is not the use of *could be playing* in those sentences.

Comment: The usages of *could* are slightly different - the first indicates possibility (John may or may not be playing with his friends right now), while the second indicates opportunity (John has the option of playing with his friends, but is definitely not at the moment).

Comment: I do see but for me the difference is not in sentences themselves. It's in the prior sentences.

Comment: The real difference here is the "*He is always reading magazines*" part.  Without that, he may or may not be playing with his friends in either case, it's just that in the second example his friends (if they are indeed playing) are implied to be in the room with him, and in the first none of them are in the room.  It's the mention of another activity - reading magazines - that heavily implies that he is in fact *not* playing with his friends.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Let's take another example: "I could be playing with my friends", she said to the person on the phone. See? Without more context, we cannot say what "she means" exactly.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct.

In #1 you are using a present tense. The conditional "could be" could be an "is".

In #2 you are using a "future" tense. (future imperfect) Speculating about what John "could" do in the future.